# sorting inside lists after operation

Tags: python, list

I have a list i need sorted after suming up the 2 numbers in the list and sorting based on that sum. The list is below..any advice would be appreciated.

```
myList = [['X5QR76', 3, 7], ['G77652', 1, 5], ['GT1885', 5, 2], ['WB2013', 5, 2], ['FINBOX', 2, 9]]
```

Comment: I just looked through your profile... I *implore* you to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167888/how-can-i-improve-my-questions-to-regain-the-ability-to-ask-questions-on-stackov), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) to avoid getting question banned. It is *really* bad to be banned, especially when you don't show effort.

Answer (score 6):

```
sorted(myList,key=lambda x:x[1]+x[2])
```

Comment: Well - it's either that or `sorted(([a, b + c] for a, b,c in myList), key=lambda L: L[1])`